# 3 TableViews with common dataSource and delegate - Wrong number of rows

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm coding an app just for fun and improvement.

My issue is the following one :

In a ViewController of my app, I've 3 tableViews sharing dataSource and delegate (the viewController it self). I've done 3 Outlets for each, this way I can identify what value return in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with an object reference comparaison (`tableView === outletTableView`).
The right values are returned each time (checked with some call to print) but the device seem to use the numberOfRows from one tableView for the 3 tableViews !
My first one had 13 rows, the second 21 and the third only 1. When the 14th row of the second tableView is loaded, the app crash with this error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000001a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 13})'
```

I've check many subjects but I haven't found any solutions...

Thanks

---

Here my code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainSkillTableHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondarySkillTableHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var exoticSkillTableHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

[...]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (tableView === mainSkillsTable) {
            print("CM \(character.main_skills.count + 1)")
            return character.main_skills.count + 1
        }
        else if (tableView === secondarySkillsTable) {
            print("CS \(character.secondary_skills.count + 1)")
            return character.secondary_skills.count + 1
        }
        else if (tableView === exoticSkillsTable) {
            print("CE \(character.exotic_skills.count + 1)")
            return character.exotic_skills.count + 1
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell1: CreationMainSkillCell?
        var cell2: CreationSecondarySkillCell?
        var cell3: CreationExoticSkillCell?
        if (tableView === mainSkillsTable) {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                return mainSkillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HeaderMainSkillCell
            }
            cell1 = mainSkillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainDataC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CreationMainSkillCell
            cell1!.character = character
            cell1!.row = indexPath.row
            return cell1!
        }
        else if (tableView === secondarySkillsTable) {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                return mainSkillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HeaderSecondarySkillCell
            }
            cell2 = mainSkillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondDataC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CreationSecondarySkillCell
            cell2!.character = character
            cell2!.row = indexPath.row
            return cell2!
        }
        else if (tableView === exoticSkillsTable) {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                return mainSkillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("exoticHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HeaderExoticSkillCell
            }
            cell3 = mainSkillsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("exoticDataC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CreationExoticSkillCell
            cell3!.character = character
            cell3!.row = indexPath.row
            return cell3!
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

---

The numberOfRows isn't linked a specific tableView ?

Comment: How can the number of rows be different if they are sharing a common data source?

Comment: Can you give detail implement? I think problem is your code wrong for each kind of table?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there seems to be something wrong with your code. It isn't possible for 3 tables to have different numberOfRows when the datasource is the same. You are apparently changing the array that you are passing to the tableView.

Keep a check on the numberOfRows that are returned when your view is loaded initially. Every time you do changes in any one table you will need to reflect the "datasource" array and not a local array. U seem to be using an intermediate array because of which u have an inconsistency in displaying the numberOfRows.

Comment: I've follow this example : https://gist.github.com/mchirico/50cdb07d20b1b0f73d7c
I've edit my post for add the code ! It's easier to understand my issue with it :p

Comment: @percypyan Is it possible for you to share the complete code? You will need to specifically set the delegates for each table separately and the data source for each table specifically.

Comment: I haven't anymore :/ I've rewrite all this part and now I use a separate delegate and dataSource class. I've create 3 objects in the Storyboard and assigned my dataSource class to each one. After that I've simply link the 3 dataSource to the 3 objects and all work perfectly !

Comment: Lol...Alright.
Close the question if you think its completed!